# Chrome Extension Notification Exception: DOM Exception 18

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webkit

I'm creating a chrome extension but I'm having some difficulties in use **notifications** webkit. When I try to display a notification, an exception is thrown:

**Uncaught Error: SecurityError: DOM Exception 18**

Bellow follow my **Javascript code**:

```
var icon  = 'icon_48.png';
var title = 'Test Plugin';
var body  = message;
var popup = window.webkitNotifications.createNotification(icon, title, body);
popup.show();
```

Bellow follow my **manifest.json**:

```
{
  "name": "Test Plugin",
  "version": "1.0.6",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "This is a test",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/icon_32.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "icons": {
      "128": "images/icon_128.png",
      "16": "images/icon_32.png",
      "48": "images/icon_48.png"
   },
  "permissions": [ 
    "http://*/*", 
    "https://*/*", 
    "contextMenus", 
    "tabs", 
    "notifications", 
    "management", 
    "webRequest" 
    ],
  "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["webtoolkit-sha1.js","content.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "css" : ["css/style.css"]
      }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["webtoolkit-sha1.js","inject.js","icon_48.png"]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks everybody!

**Information Update:**

manifest.json has the attribute **notifications** in **permissions** section but when I print the *webkitNotifications.checkPermission()* the result was 1 (PERMISSION_NOT_ALLOWED).

Answer (score 1):

The `notifications` permission only applies to the extension's process. In order to get your code to work, a [background](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) (or [event](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html)) page needs to be added, which creates the notification. The content script can use the [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) API to request the notification.